# Why to use fluentmigrator?

Tags: entity-framework, fluent-migrator

When and why to use [FluentMigrator](https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator) as Entity Framework [Code-First Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/) does the same job.

The two appear to be very similar, what problem or flaw does *FluentMigrator* solve when EF already provides classes to manipulate the database schema.

I am not clear why and when(in which cases) to use fluentmigrator?

Answer (score 2):

Not everybody uses Entity Framework. I don't use it in my current project for example. In this scenario FluentMigrator is very useful for managing the database changes for each release.

Answer (score 1):

EntityFramework kind of gives you both tasks: ORM and migration (CodeFirst).

I, for instance, use NHibernate and use FluentMigrator. The first as ORM and the second as the database migration library. You could say indeed that I am writing two faces of the same concept so it is more maintenance costs, however, I prefer higher control over this (ORM and migration separately) because you could screw up very easily if it's not explicit up front.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the examples above: in case you use some Micro ORM like [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/), you'll need a separate tool for database migrations. That's what [Fluent Migrator](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/quickstart.html) is all about.